# Can someone please explain why $\log\left(\frac{z-1}{z+1}\right)$ has branch points at 1 and -1

Tags: branch-cuts

Can someone please explain

a) why $\log\left(\frac{z-1}{z+1}\right)$ has branch points at 1 and -1. I know what a branch point is as it is defined in my text. I've seen that sometimes we have a branch cut along the negative real axis for $log(z)$. Is there one of those as well for $\log\left(\frac{z-1}{z+1}\right)$

b) how to put $\log\left(\frac{z-1}{z+1}\right)$ into the standard complex form like how $\log(z) = \log(r) + i\theta$

[image]
Thanks

Comment: what definition of branch point are you working with? there are a few, and some are easier to work with than others.

Comment: ah ok. in that case what definition of "branch cut" are you using, and do you want a formal proof, or just an intuitive one? 

Comment: That's very kind, I would like both if possible, if the formal one is too big than intuitive is fine. I am really struggling because I know depending upon how $\theta$ is defined $\log(z)$ can have a branch cut at any of the axis, but I can't convert this function to the format given in example 1 in the image. I am wondering as well if you could do that, and explain to me if $\log{(z-1)/(z+1)}$ is multivalued anywhere, because that's normally where branch cuts come into play. As defined in my text: a branch cut is a line used to create a domain of analyticity

Comment: I only had the most basic course in complex variables, so I'm guessing log(z-1)-log(z+1) has those branch points because log(z-1) has a branch point at 1 and log(z+1) has a branch point at -1, because log(z) has a branch point at 0. Something like that. Do you understand why log(z) has a branch point at z=0?

Comment: If $z$ moves from $+i$ to $-i$ passing through $0$, then what happens to $(z-1)/(z+1)$?

Comment: Branch points for log are at points where the argument is zero.  Here at z=1 and z=-1.

Answer (score 1):

$\log$ is "always" multivalued, as $\log(x)\sim \log(x) + 2\pi i$, regardless of what $x \;(\neq 0)$ is! One question, though, is whether you always need a branch cut. One way of showing that you need a branch cut is by showing that for a family of mutually nonintersecting closed curves, the function is locally holomorphic but not possibly analytic on each of those curves. One way to do *that* (at least sometimes) is to phrase your function as the antiderivative of another function along those curves, and then show that the value at a given point on each of those curves is not well-defined.

That is, the integral of the derivative of $f$ around each of those curves—which should be the difference between $f$ at the beginning and end, which here are the same point, and therefore should be $0$—is actually nonzero. Here, $f(z)=\log\left(\frac{z-1}{z+1}\right)$ and $f'(z)=\frac{1}{z-1}-\frac{1}{z+1}$.

So, explicitly, for a curve $\gamma^+_{a\mapsto a}$ encircling $z=1$ but not $z=-1$, which starts and ends at $a$:
$$\begin{align}
0 &= \left[\log\left(\frac{z-1}{z+1}\right)\right]_{z=a}^a \\
&= \int_{\gamma^+_{a\mapsto a}}\frac{1}{z-1}-\frac{1}{z+1}\ dz \\
&=\text{res}_{z=1}\frac{1}{z-1} - 0 \\
&=2\pi i
\end{align}$$
Likewise, for a curve $\gamma^-_{a\mapsto a}$ encircling $z=-1$ but not $z=1$:
$$\begin{align}
0 &= \left[\log\left(\frac{z-1}{z+1}\right)\right]_{z=a}^a \\
&= \int_{\gamma^-_{a\mapsto a}}\frac{1}{z-1}-\frac{1}{z+1}\ dz \\
&=0 - \text{res}_{z=-1}\frac{1}{z+1} \\
&=-2\pi i
\end{align}$$

So, $f$ cannot be (single-valued) analytic on any domain containing such curves, lest we get a contradiction. If a (sufficiently nice) branch cut, therefore, did not include $-1$ and did not include $1$, we could arrive at a contradiction by going sufficiently close to one of those and repeating the above. So, $-1$ and $1$ need to be in every (sufficiently nice) branch cut. (There's a little more technical reasoning we could do here, but I'm guessing your text allows certain assumptions on what a "line" is or gives proof techniques for finding branch points that are a bit simpler than that would involve.)

These are the only branch points: after choosing a branch cut, we can define $\log\left(\frac{z-1}{z+1}\right)$ to be the integral of $\frac{1}{z-1}-\frac{1}{z+1}$ along some path to the point in question, plus whatever integer multiple of $2\pi i$ we like.

Let's construct a nice branch cut: the interval $[-1,1]$. Note that we get no contradiction by encircling the whole branch cut with a curve, since the residues cancel out. This is what we get by using the principal branch of $\log$ in our definition. Here's what $f$ looks like with that branch cut:
[image: a plot of the function above]

We could also choose many other branch cuts, of course, as long as they include $-1$ and $1$ (including the branch cut with "disconnected" branches $(-\infty,-1]$, $[1,\infty)$) and as long as the resulting branch satisfies $e^{f(z_0)}=\frac{z_0-1}{z_0+1}$ at some point $z_0$.

Takeaway message: you can usually expect $\log$ to be multivalued, and to require a branch cut whenever there's a pole somewhere, since integrating the derivative around that pole will likely give you a residue.

As for getting the real and imaginary parts, it depends on your branch cut! If you use the principal branch of $\log$, you can break it up as $\log\left|\frac{z-1}{z+1}\right|+i\arg\left(\frac{z-1}{z+1}\right)$—and then if you want to simplify those in terms of $z=re^{i\theta}$, you might want to do some trig.

Let me know if anything here is unclear!